# Declare and return a json variable with postgresql function

Tags: json, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function PostgreSQL to check if a user exist in a table users by creating a function who return a JSON variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login( uname character varying(55),pswd character varying(55)) 
RETURNS json AS
$$
DECLARE
  msg json ;
BEGIN
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=uname and password=pswd) AS row_count) =1)
THEN
msg="{ 'stat' : 'active' }";
    RETURN msg;
ELSE
msg="{ 'stat' : 'inactive' }";
    RETURN msg;
END IF;    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I try to using it it's return me the following error:
ERROR:  column "{ 'stat' : 'inactive' }" does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL (and PL/pgSQL). And JSON uses double quotes for keys and values, so `{ 'stat' : 'active' }` is invalid JSON as well.

You need:

```
msg := '{"stat": "active"}';
```

The variable isn't really needed, you could also use:

```
return '{"stat": "active"}';
```

---

Note that the IF condition can be made a bit more efficient by using an EXISTS condition:

```
if exists (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=uname and password=pswd) 
then 
  ...
```